# checked checkbox's value shown in listbox after button click

Tags: c#, checkbox, listbox

Ok here is my question. I assign value to each checkboxes I created, and am trying to put them into listbox only when they are checked, after a button click. So here is the code that I have written so far, in which when the button is clicked, both the values are written into listbox, whether they are checked or not, how can I make it work as I explained?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnOne.Click += btnOne_Click;
        chckOne.CheckedChanged += chckOne_CheckedChanged;
        chckTwo.CheckStateChanged += chckTwo_CheckStateChanged;
    }
    void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        lstOne.Items.Add(number1 + number2);
    }

    string number1 = "ONE", number2 = "TWO";
    void chckOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            lstOne.Items.Add(number1);
        }
     }

    void chckTwo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            lstOne.Items.Add(number2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why are u creating new checkbox object. get value from checkbox existed on form

Comment: Correct your code. Be careful when posting.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<CheckBox> cbList=new List<CheckBox>();

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        btnOne.Click += btnOne_Click;
        cbList.Add(chckOne);
        cbList.Add(chckTwo);
        //All the checkbox should be added into cbList.
}

void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    lstOne.Items.Clear();  
    var checked_checkbox = cbList.Where(cb=>cb.Checked==true).ToList();
    if(checked_checkbox.Count>0)
    {
        checked_checkbox.ForEach(x=>lstOne.Items.Add(x.Text));// Maybe you want put text of checkbox into listbox.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define one method:

```
void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    if (chk.Checked == true)
    {
        lstOne.Items.Add(chkBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        lstOne.Items.Remove(chkBox.Text);
    }
}
```

And attach it all your CheckBox `CheckedChanged` events:

```
 chckOne.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
 chckTwo.CheckStateChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

Or if you want to add all checked values in your Button click change your method like this:

```
void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                 .Where(c => c.Checked == true)
                 .Select(c => c.Text)
                 .ForEach(text => lstOne.Items.Add(text));
}
```